# How to create custom object that auto generate content code when inherit it?

Tags: ios, objective-c

With native iOS SDK, if we create custom object and set subclass like UIViewController or else, the custom object will auto generate content code like "

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil"
```

in .m file.

Now I'm trying to create custom object `ObjectA(subclass is NSObject)`, and create custom object `ObjectB(subclass is ObjectA)`, the new ObjectB is empty.

How to create ObjectA that can impact the new object's content which inherit it?

Comment: I don't think you can.  You'll have to type it into a text editor.

Comment: Thank you, and by Maxime LM's answer, create custom file template works fine and it's reduce so many routines.

Comment: Excellent.  In a year's time you should have quite a collection of custom templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating a custom file template. It will appear in a new category in the New File... window : http://www.bobmccune.com/2012/03/04/creating-custom-xcode-4-file-templates/

I use it to replace the default header in all my source files.

Comment: Cool! It's works fine after create custom file template. Thank you for sharing!